# Split align over pages in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context

Consider the following code example:

```
\setuppapersize[A8,landscape][A8,landscape]
\starttext
\startformula
    \startalign
        \NC 1 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 2 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 3 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 4 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 5 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 6 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 7 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 8 \NC= 1\NR
    \stopalign
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Coming from a LaTeX background I would expect `align` to break over pages and [this myway article from 2006](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf) tells me

> Somewhere between March and Arpril, `\startalign` lost the ability to break equations across pages. Hopefully, it will be added back soon.

So basically it is intended to have page breaks, isn't it? *Question:* How to enable them for align?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the change in functionality, but I found a reference to `\startsplitformula` in the [math manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/math-mkiv), page 61. The following seems to work (whereas a normal `\startformula` doesn't):

```
\setuppapersize[A8,landscape][A8,landscape]
\starttext
  \startsplitformula
    \startmathalignment
        \NC 1 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 2 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 3 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 4 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 5 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 6 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 7 \NC= 1\NR
        \NC 8 \NC= 1\NR
    \stopmathalignment
  \stopsplitformula
\stoptext
```

It should be noted that the manual also refers to this approach as "experimental".